# redirect out of wp-admin, without losing admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, wp-redirect

I'm trying to keep all non-administrators out of the Wordpress admin panel by using a wp_redirect inside of an is_admin conditional. The problem is that a side effect of this if that non-admins can no longer use the file "admin-ajax.php" for ajax calls in Wordpress. It appears that [a few people on the Wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/dont-redirect-admin-ajax?replies=4#post-2286531) are having the exact same problem lately.

Would anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the `DOING_AJAX` constant:

```
function my_admin_init(){
    if( !defined('DOING_AJAX') && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','my_admin_init');
```

Comment: I'd switch to `manage_options` in case some plugin changes the name of the 'administrator'  role. Anyway, I'd +10 this if i could :)